# TypeError: append() takes no keyword arguments - Python code for multiprocessing to get fractal dimentions of a image

Tags: python, image, numpy, math, typeerror

I am currently on a project to make a multiprocessing fractal dimention calculation program.

I designed the code so that it would first split big image to 9 pieces and calculate fractal dimention of each part.

```
from multiprocessing import process
import numpy as np
import os
import math as mt   
import cv2
import imageio
import warnings
from PIL import Image
warnings.simplefilter('ignore', Image.DecompressionBombWarning)
Image.MAX_IMAGE_PIXELS = None
def fractal_dimension(Z, threshold=0.8):
"""Returns box-counting dimension of a 2D array.
    Args:
        Z: 2D array to be analysed.
        threshold: Cutoff for converting values in Z to 1 and 0.
    Returns:
        The estimated box counting dimension.
"""

    # Only for 2d image
    assert(len(Z.shape) == 2)
    # From https://github.com/rougier/numpy-100 (#87)
    def boxcount(Z, k):
        S = np.add.reduceat(
            np.add.reduceat(Z, np.arange(0, Z.shape[0], k), axis=0),
                               np.arange(0, Z.shape[1], k), axis=1)
        # We count non-empty (0) and non-full boxes (k*k)
        return len(np.where((S > 0) & (S < k*k))[0])
    # Transform Z into a binary array
    Z = (Z < threshold)
    # Minimal dimension of image
    p = min(Z.shape)
    # Greatest power of 2 less than or equal to p
    n = 2**np.floor(np.log(p)/np.log(2))
    # Extract the exponent
    n = int(np.log(n)/np.log(2))
    # Build successive box sizes (from 2**n down to 2**1)
    sizes = 2**np.arange(n, 1, -1)
    # Actual box counting with decreasing size
    counts = []
    for size in sizes:
        counts.append(boxcount(Z, size))
    # Fit the successive log(sizes) with log (counts)
    coeffs = np.polyfit(np.log(sizes), np.log(counts), 1)
    #fracd.append(coeffs)
    return -coeffs[0]

I = imageio.imread(r"C:\Users\qkrgn\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\Van_Gogh_-_Starry_Night_-_Google_Art_Project.jpg", as_gray="True")/255.0    # Import the image in greyscale
print("Minkowski–Bouligand dimension (computed): ", fractal_dimension(I))

subset_9t1 = I[::3, ::3]
subset_9t2 = I[1::3, ::3]
subset_9t3 = I[2::3, ::3]
subset_9t4 = I[::3, 1::3]
subset_9t5 = I[1::3, 1::3]
subset_9t6 = I[2::3, 1::3]
subset_9t7 = I[::3, 2::3]
subset_9t8 = I[1::3, 2::3]
subset_9t9 = I[2::3, 2::3]
if __name__ =='__main__':

    processes:list = []

    processes.append(target=fractal_dimension, args=subset_9t1)
    processes.append(target=fractal_dimension, args=subset_9t2)
    processes.append(target=fractal_dimension, args=subset_9t3)
    processes.append(target=fractal_dimension, args=subset_9t4)
    processes.append(target=fractal_dimension, args=subset_9t5)
    processes.append(target=fractal_dimension, args=subset_9t6)
    processes.append(target=fractal_dimension, args=subset_9t7)
    processes.append(target=fractal_dimension, args=subset_9t8)
    processes.append(target=fractal_dimension, args=subset_9t9)
    
for process in processes:
    process.start()

print(sum(fracd, 0.000)/len(fracd))
```

The error code reads:

```
traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/qkrgn/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/main.py", line 141, in <module>
    processes.append(target=fractal_dimension, args=subset_9t1)
TypeError: append() takes no keyword arguments
```

I want to know why this error comes up& how to fix it. and wether there would be any problem in splitting a image to calculate fractal dimention and combining them back to get the fractal dimention.

Comment: Show us the documentation for this method.  I don't recognize it.  The `list.append` method does not document those arguments.

Answer (score 1):

You should do it this way instead of what you are actually doing.

```py
from multiprocessing import Process

# make this change for all the times you tried to append it while using the earlier way.
processes.append(Process(target=fractal_dimension, args=[subset_9t1]))
```

You were passing keyword arguments which don't exist for append function which is what you don't wanna do.

Also instead of manually typing those appends you can use a for loop

```py
if __name__ == '__main__':
    VARIABLE_NAME = "subset_9t"
    
    for i in range(1, 10):
        p = Process(target=fractal_dimension, args=[eval(VARIABLE_NAME + str(i))])
        processes.append(p)
```